# Warn: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the " + ... MERN Stack Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

Why my setUser returns that warning when I console.log it? :

```
function dispatchAction(fiber, queue, action) {
  {
    if (typeof arguments[3] === 'function') {
      error("State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the " + 'second callback argument. To execute a side effect after ' + 'rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().');
    }
  }
```

Here is the function:

```
const UserContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`${API}/auth/user`, {
            method: 'GET',
            withCredentials: true,
            credentials: 'include'
        })
        .then (response => response.json())
        .then (response => {
            setUser(response.user)
            console.log(setUser)
        })
        .catch (error => {
            console.error (error);
        });
    }, [setUser])
```

Note: The response.user is just an object. And I can access the data in the user with no problem in the children components.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too; in my case it was happening because I wasn't declaring all of the passed contexts in child components. For instance, in my provider I had:

```
<Outlet context={[user, setUser, filter, setFilter]} />
```

But I was only declaring the content states within my child components:

```
const [user, filter] = useOutletContext();
```

So it was thinking that the `filter` state was the setter for `user`. I changed it to include all of the passed contexts:

```
const [user, setUser, filter, setFilter] = useOutletContext();
```

And it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to see the api data? in the clg print user from your useState.

const UserContextProvider = (props) => {
const [user, setUser] = useState({})

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${API}/auth/user`, {
        method: 'GET',
        withCredentials: true,
        credentials: 'include'
    })
    .then (response => response.json())
    .then (response => {
        setUser(response.user)
        console.log(user)
    })
    .catch (error => {
        console.error (error);
    });
}, [setUser])
```